# Which ip i should put on the url of my php request?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an application which basically starts with registration system using the wampserver  to connect to mysql database through localhost/phpmyadmin as a back-end and android client using genymotion emulator as a front-end and both front and back end communicates through php/mysql API.

I have followed different tutorials to achieve all this but since none of them actually used genymotion I am missing the part of which IP, I should put for this mechanism to follow smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

when you use emulator on you pc , your emulator will connect to virtual network interface that you can change it ....

you should check emulator network interface and enter your pc ip in that network interface ...

i attached a picture of setting of my emulator and you can see my emulator use my wifi network interface .... thus i should insert my computer ip address of wifi network interface

finally you should get your pc ip as network interface that your emulator connected to that and use that ip in emulator for connect to your webserver in your pc.....

[image]

in Wampserver, you can not access to apache from outside ...

you should change apache config (httpd.conf) and make access for outside connection ...

Comment: @Roboticexpert Some clear steps will do me good, if you don't mind :D